# java garbage collector callbacks

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

While using jvisualvm to locate performance issues I found that my java application(1000s of classes) is creating a lot of temporary objects(say X) during an operation which are eligible of GC after the operation only a small number of objects(say Y) are refrenciable.
Reducing the number of temporary objects can possibly lead to performance improvements(CPU cycles to create, delete/GC objects and RAM).
The information which is missing is the types or temporary objects being created. I can visit the code and try to find out but that will take a lot of time to trace all the code flows.

An alternate method I can think of is to ask GC to put a message in log stating which type of object is being freed, this will give me hints about the possible culprits.

Does the java GC have any facilities to provide this information?

Comment: Use tools like AppDynamics (There are other alternatives too), that should quickly help you in identifying contentious code.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Java garbage collector is _really really good_ at dealing with the case where there's a lot of very short-lived objects created.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to get a per object logging or callbacks from GC, but you can get accumulated statistics programmatically via JMX. This [article](http://www.fasterj.com/articles/gcnotifs.shtml) shows how to get notifications from `GarbageCollectorMXBean` instances documented by Oracle [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/overview.html).

Maybe you're peeling a banana at the wrong end. Instead of concentrating on what happens with the dead objects, you can monitor memory snapshots showing your live objects. You can do this with `VisualVM` on the fly, or save memory dumps with `jmap` utility. This will give you a lot of input for optimizing your memory profile. After all, what do you expect from GC monitoring? All that goes up must go down. All live objects will be dead at some point. Check your live objects.

Comment: My problem is that the temporary/short lived objects are too large in number (~ 1GB worth of RAM) and the actual number of object which are not temporary are ~200 MB. That means that at runtime the application creates write/reads 1GB data from RAM and invokes the corresponding constructors. One possible way to improve performance is to not create so many temp object and pass a single object around.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `finalize()` method ([more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize())) and print out some information there.

> Called by the garbage collector on an object when garbage collection determines that there are no more references to the object. A subclass overrides the finalize method to dispose of system resources or to perform other cleanup.

Comment: Well this seems to be for debugging only so I guess it's ok

Comment: using finalizers will give me the required info but I have to add finalizers for all my classes, I am looking for shortcuts :).

Comment: Is there a global callback that I can use, that will tell me for a specific class (and its sub-classes) when they are GC-ed ?

Answer (score 0):

JDK has tool called `jmap` which can report distribution of objects by classes - class histogram. It does it for live object though.

By taking multiple class histograms and comparing them it is possible to construct similar histogram by dead classes.

I have automated this process you can you [sjk](https://github.com/aragozin/jvm-tools) tools and `hh` command to produce class histograms for garbage in your heap.

[Here](https://github.com/aragozin/jvm-tools/blob/master/sjk-core/COMMANDS.md#hh-command) you can find more details.